# How to make div flow inwards with specific parent height when resizing window?

Tags: html, css

I want to understand how I can make sure that two `divs` or spans can be made to only flow inside their parent section that has a specific width already, so that when an user resizes his window it flows inwards.

Specifically the code that I am to provide, the logo should go above the header once the menu is shown from tablets..

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
<section id="navigation">

    <div class="nav-body">

        <section class="logo">
            <div style="background:green;height: 30px;"></div>
        </section>

        <section class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>one</li>
                 <li>two</li>
                 <li>three</li>
                 <li>four</li>
                 <li>five</li>
                 <li>six</li>
                 <li>seven</li>

            </ul
        </section>

    </div>

</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmckLb36/1/

Comment: Have you considered looking at a responsive CSS framework, like Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Not what I am looking for, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 1029px;` and add `width: 100%;` as shown below:

```
#navigation > .nav-body {
    width: 100%; 
    margin:0 auto;
    resize:both;
}
```

Comment: Let's say the .nav-body needs to be centered within the page that is 1200px, so I need that 1029px to center it, make sense?

Comment: you can use percentage instead of pixels